# How to check if iPhone supports CDMA or GSM

Tags: iphone, ios4, gsm, cellular-network, cdma

Is there any way to identify if iPhone supports CDMA or GSM network. Any Apple API in Objective-C which can provide this information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might examine model id with the function ([credits](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/device/determine-if-iphone-is-3g-or-3gs-determine-if-ipod-is-first-or-second-generation.html)):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
NSString* machine () {
        size_t size;

            // Set 'oldp' parameter to NULL to get the size of the data
            // returned so we can allocate appropriate amount of space
        sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0); 

            // Allocate the space to store name
        char *name = malloc(size);

            // Get the platform name
        sysctlbyname("hw.machine", name, &size, NULL, 0);

            // Place name into a string
        NSString *machineid = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:name];

            // Done with this
        free(name);

        return machineid;
    }
```

Function will return string like @"iPhone3,3" which stands for iPhone 4 (CDMA/Verizon). It might be difficult to gather full table of various model numbers. Some of the models descriptions could be found [here](http://www.everyipod.com/iphone-specs/index-iphone.html). You'll have to expand table of models as new models will appear.