# Is it possible to determine the iPhone 4s's network type (GSM/CDMA) in iOS5

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

Is it possible to determine the iPhone 4s's network type (GSM/CDMA)?
Is there a way to determine the iPhone 4s's network type (GSM/CDMA).I want to distinguish between GSM/WCDMA and CDMA if possible. I use the following codes to detect it .

```
    size_t size;
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
char *machine = malloc(size);
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:machine];
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone 4S";
if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,3"])    return @"iPhone 4S coma";
```

But I test it with my coma and wcdma iphone4s。
It both return iPhone4,1. I can not distinguish it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9525305/is-it-possible-to-determine-the-network-type-gsm-cdma ?

Comment: Answered http://stackoverflow.com/q/7596079/1487063

Answer (score 0):

You could use the carrier that is being used as an indicator.

```
NSString* networkType = nil;

// Setup the Network Info and create a CTCarrier object
// first check to ensure the developper linked the CoreTelephony framework
Class telephonyClass = NSClassFromString(@"CTTelephonyNetworkInfo");
if ( nil != telephonyClass ) {
    CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *networkInfo = [[[telephonyClass alloc] init] autorelease];

    if ( nil != networkInfo ) {
       // Get mobile network code
        NSString *mnc = [carrier mobileNetworkCode];
        if (mnc != nil) {   
             // set networkType based on carrier name
             // carrier name to network type mapping left as an exercise for the reader
             //
        }
    }
}
```